# Apache User Directory URL

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I have a SUSE server running and it is configured allow users to login with their windows credentials.  I have apache with user directories turned on. So that users could upload their sites to the public_html directory.  The problem is that the URL to access their sites is:
192.168.1.1/~DOMAIN\windowsusername/

The backslash is undesirable in a URL.  How can I map or rewrite the URL so that 192.168.1.1/~windowsusername would take them to what is currently 192.168.1.1/~DOMAIN\windowsusername/ ?

Comment: Details about how, exactly, you've configured your SuSE server would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should do it.  Not 100% sure how the backslash will behave in the replacement, may require some tweaking (turning `\` into `\\`).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]*)/(.*)$ /~DOMAIN\$1/$2
```